# Iterative method for solving a linear system - convergence

Tags: numerical-methods

I have to solve the following linear system using an iterative method :
$\begin{cases}
   &4x_1+x_2 = b_1 \\
   &x_{i-1}+4x_i + x_{i+1}=b_i,\  i=2 \cdots n-1\\
   &x_{n-1} + 4x_n=b_n
  \end{cases}$

The iterative method is

$\begin{cases}
x_1^{k+1} = \alpha x_1^{(k)} + \frac{\alpha-1}{4}(x_2^{(k)}-b_1)\\
x_i^{k+1} = \alpha x_i^{(k)} + \frac{\alpha-1}{4}(x_{i-1}^{(k)}+x_{i+1}^{(k)}-b_i),\  i=2 \cdots n-1\\
x_n^{k+1} = \alpha x_n^{(k)} + \frac{\alpha-1}{4}(x_{n-1}^{(k)}-b_n)\\
\end{cases}$

where $\alpha$ is a real and $x^{(0)}=0$.

I have to prove first that
$\parallel x^{(k+1)}-x \parallel_\infty \leq \left(|\alpha| + \left|\frac{\alpha-1}{2}\right|\right) \parallel x^{(k)}-x \parallel_\infty
$

I tried lot of things but without success. I am sure that I have to use a proof by induction, but I cannot prove that the initialization is true for $k=0$.
Can you help me?

Comment: Begin your work by expressing your iteration using matrices and vectors. Exploit that your matrix is strictly diagonally dominant.

Answer (score 1):

The $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$ norm of you iteration matrix is precisely $|\alpha| +\frac{|\alpha-1|}{2}$, so the result comes directly from the fixed point theorem.